# Verify connection before form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to verify the user's internet connection before form submit, so that my JavaScript validation function can throw an alert and return false if no connection.

I've tried:
navigator.onLine - doesn't work in FF (only looks at whether browser in 'offline mode')

AJAX request to my own site:

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "GET",  
  url: "internet_test.php",  
  async: false, //trying to force a response before continuing
  timeout:8000,
  success: function(ret_text) {
    if(ret_text == 'yes') {
      return true;
    } else {
      alert("No Connection 1");
      return false;
    }
  },
  error: function(x, t, m) {
    if(t==="timeout") {
      alert("No Connection 2");
      return false;
    } else {
      alert("No Connection 3");  //this is the one triggered
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

I get the alert for the third type of error, but then the form submits anyway.  I'm guessing that the error overrides the fact that I tried to specify a synchronous check, and the JavaScript validator finishes before the AJAX can return false.

Is there a good way around this?  Better way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: If they didn't have an Internet connection, how would they be getting to your form in the first place?

Comment: What are you receiving in `ret_text`?

Comment: @j08691: It can cut out.  I got a complaint from a user that he lost his data when his spotty internet was down as he tried to submit, and it seems like a reasonable concern for long forms

Comment: @EmCo: internet_test.php is just <?php echo 'yes'; ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go this way:

1. Change the "submit" to "button" (or link) - it will stop submitting form.
2. On-click for this button make an AJAX call and if everything is OK, then make form.submit();

It's just a draft, everything can be made more user-friendly, more robust for no-js browsers etc.